# Do I have to reset variables in my ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`.

In Storyboard, `ViewControllerA` transitions to `ViewControllerB` once a button is clicked.

In `ViewControllerB` there is another button that increments the value `count`.

No matter the value of `count`, when the user presses the back button and comes back to `ViewControllerB`, I would assume that `count` have the value of `0` again, but it remains at the previously incremented value.

Why is this happening? Should I be resetting the value to 0 each time in `viewWillAppear` or something?

In case it matters: the variable is not a property, it is declared at the top of `ViewControllerB.m` as `int count = 0;`.

Comment: How exactly are you transitioning from view controller A to B?

Comment: I have assigned a segue from a `UIButton` to `ViewControllerB` and used `push` as the transition option. Both `ViewController` `A` and `B` are part of the same `NavigationController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In case it matters: the variable is not a property, it is declared at the top of ViewControllerB.m as int count = 0;"

Yes it does matter - your variable has nothing whatsoever to do with ViewControllerB so therefore it won't get reset. 
When the view controller is loaded it is not  the .m file that gets loaded each time! It is the view controller within it.

Your variable is a global variable and its lifetime is that of the app not of the view controller.

Comment: Well this worked, thanks a lot. I have to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer. Quick question: even when variables aren't defined as static they are global to the applications if defined the way I had it?

Comment: Making it static affects which other parts of the app can see it, effectively making it private to that file.

Comment: It depends where you have declared your variable. Before or within the `@interface` / `@end` block or the `@implementation` / `@end` block.